# Deutsche Entsprechung zu Karen?

Tags: single-word-request, person-names

Der weibliche Vorname  [*Karen*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Karen) wird im Englischen seit wenigen Jahren exemplarisch für den Stereotyp der beschwerdefreudigen, hellhäutigen Vorstadtmittelklassehausfrau aus der „Boomer“-Generation mit Minivan oder SUV verwendet. Gibt es einen äquivalenten Vornamen im deutschen Sprachraum, der ähnlich verwendet wird oder sich aufgrund vergleichbarer [demographischer Eigenschaften](https://www.behindthename.com/name/karen-1/top) dafür anböte? (*Karen* war in den USA etwa von 1940 bis 1965 besonders populär.)

Comment: _Karin_ wäre zu einfach, oder?

Comment: Manche nutzen Alliteration und sprechen von *Alman-Annika*

Comment: "Belastete" Vornamen in ähnlicher Rolle (aber mit ganz anderer Bedeutung) sind wohl allenfalls Kevin und Chantal

Comment: Ich befürchte, "Karen" wäre "Sabine" (der wahrscheinlich typischste Baby-Boomer-Frauenname)

Comment: Even as an American you have to be fairly plugged in to social media to know what a "Karen" is; I suspect by 2023 it will have disappeared in favor of the next buzzword. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_(pejorative) or (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_(Meme).

Comment: Schließe mich der Meinung an daß das 'Phänomen' in Deutschland seltener als z.B. in USA ist. Ich war selber überrascht als bei längeren Aufenthalten in USA in den späten 80ern und 90ern vielfach auf die 'what's in it for me' Mentalität stieß. Deutschland ist wohl nicht ganz so konsumorientiert wie USA. Idee: Wie heißt denn die typische Kosmtikberaterin, falls es die alten Lederhäute noch gibt ? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich habe nicht den Eindruck, dass es das Phänomen in Deutschland oder Europa in wirklich vergleichbarer Form gibt.

Die typische "Karen" ist eine amerikanische weiße Generation-X- oder Boomer-Frau, die gewohnt ist, dass sie mehr erreicht, wenn sie mit genügend Energie auf jeder noch so unberechtigten Forderung beharrt. Das typische Beispiel ist ihr Verhalten als Kunde. Schon die Kundenservice-Mentalität, die dafür die Voraussetzung ist, gibt es in der gleichen Form nicht in Europa. Das "Karens" zugeschriebene typische Zitat "I need to speak to the manager" / "I will complain to Corporate" ist auch  kein so typisches Verhalten in Europa.

Letzlich ist das Karen-Verhalten ja eine Variante des geradezu stereotypisch amerikanischen "Stand your ground", des kompromisslosen Beharrens auf dem eigenen Standpunkt und seiner Verteidigung. Vielleicht kommt das in Europa noch, wenn unsere Gesellschaft eine ähnliche Polarisierung und Zersplitterung erfährt, aber es hat in Amerika in verschiedenen Formen auch eine sehr lange Tradition.

Wir sind in Deutschland immer schnell damit, amerikanische gesellschaftliche Phänomene 1:1 auf deutsche Verhältnise zu übertragen, aber meist gibt es bei uns eigentlich ganz andere Verhaltensweisen und rote Linien.

Begriffe wie "Alman", "Ökotante", "Wutbürger", "Querdenker", "Helikoptermama" sind umgekehrt schwer mit ihren Konnotationen in andere Sprachen zu übersetzen.

Comment: "Ich will sofort den Geschäftsführer sprechen" kenne ich schon, allerdings mehr aus der Kindheit (70er Jahre) und fast ausschliesslich im Zusammenhang mit (Sketchen über die ) Gastronomie, als Verhalten/Karikatur von Snobs, die sich vom Oberkellner (auch so ein ausgestorbenes Wort) nicht angemessen behandelt fühlen. Vielleicht waren wir da einfach schneller als die Amerikaner :-)

Comment: Auch diesen Boomer-vs-Millennial-Quatsch gibt es so meines Wissens in Europa nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Mir ist nichts dergleichen bekannt. Das liegt vermutlich vor allem daran, dass in Europa die Städte anderes strukturiert sind als in den USA, und es so etwas wie eine Vorstadtmittelschichthausfrau, die einen Minivan oder SUV fährt, in Europa fast gar nicht gibt.

Wenn eine europäische Frau Hausfrau ist und einen Minivan oder SUV hat, gehört sie nicht zur Mittelschicht sondern zu einer wohlhabenden Oberschicht. Es gibt zwar Vororte, in denen Villen stehen vor denen solche Fahrzeuge parken, aber das sind die teuren Villen-Viertel und keine Mittelschicht-Gegenden.

Wer zur Mittelschicht gehört und in einer europäischen Stadt wohnt, benutzt entweder öffentliche Verkehrsmittel oder hat einen Kleinwagen.

---

Häufigkeiten von Vornamen in bestimmten Jahren findet man hier:

- [1940](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/jahrgang/j1940)
- [1960](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/jahrgang/j1960)
- usw.

Klickt man dort auf einen bestimmten Vornamen, wird eine Statistik-Seite zu diesem Vornamen angezeigt. Beispielsweise

- [Karin](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/4919-karin.htm)
- [Sabine](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/5024-sabine.htm)

Comment: "Wer zur Mittelklasse gehört und in einer europäischen Stadt wohnt, benutzt entweder öffentliche Verkehrsmittel oder hat einen Kleinwagen." Das ist eine seltsame Definition von Mittelklasse. In den meisten deutschen Mittelklassehaushalten ist der Kleinwagen das Zweitauto. Selbstverständlich fährt ein erheblicher Anteil der deutschen Mittelklasse einen Minivan oder SUV als Erstfahrzeug.

Comment: Eigentlich ist es ja ohnehin so, dass man, wenn man zur Mittelklasse gehört, ein Fahrzeug ist. »Mittelklasse« ist die Bezeichnung für PKWs mit bestimmten Eigenschaften. Menschen gehören zu sozialen Schichten, eine davon ist die Mittelschicht. Ich hatte das in meiner Antwort ursprünglich auch falsch und habe es nun korrigiert.

Answer (score 2):

İch denke das ist einer der Fälle in denen der Begriff "entlehnt" wird. Der entsprechende Begriff ist auch im deutschen Sprachraum "Karen".