# Typische deutsche Vornamen nach Generation

Tags: person-names

Es gibt in der (Populär-)Soziologie verschiedene Ansätze, die Bevölkerung nach Geburtsjahr in Kohorten, sogenannte *Generationen* einzuteilen. Die Größe beträgt meist etwa 15 bis 20 Jahrgänge. Für die Erstellung von Personas, die sich zum Teil auf diese Einteilung beziehen, stelle ich mir gerade die Frage:
**Welcher** weibliche und welcher männliche **Vorname kann** im deutschen Sprachraum jeweils **exemplarisch für die Mitglieder dieser Generationen stehen**, weil er zwar in diesem Zeitraum aber weder davor noch danach besonders beliebt war?

Ich nehme hierfür in etwa die folgenden Kohorten à ca. 15 Jahre an, wobei ich mir unsicher bin, ob das sinnvoll für den gesamten Sprachraum möglich ist, insbesondere während der deutschen Teilung:

- ab 2010 *Generation Alpha*
- 1995–2010 *Generation Z*, *Zoomer*
- 1980–1995 *Generation Y*, *Millenials*
- 1965–1980 *Generation X*, *Generation Golf*
- 1945–1965 *(Baby) Boomer*, *Nachkriegsgeneration*
- 1930–1945 Kriegsgeneration
- vor 1930

Beispiel: *Erika* Mustermann könnte vielleicht für die Kriegsgeneration stehen, während *Max* Mustermann nicht genau zuzuordnen ist: entweder noch älter oder (späte) Generation Z.

Comment: PS: Ich habe schonmal eine ähnliche Frage gestellt https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65375/deutsche-entsprechung-zu-karen

Comment: Googlen nach "vornamen beliebtheit nach jahrgang" gibt mir das hier: https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/jahrgang Damit solltest du in der Lage sein, deine Frage zu beantworten, je nachdem, welche Kriterien du genau anlegst.

Comment: Kurz als Bemerkung zu der Liste: In Deutschland kam der Babyboom ca. 10 Jahre später als in den USA, der amerikanische Begriff "Boomer" passt hier gar nicht so gut.

Comment: Re: HalvarF Ja, 1946-1955 Nachkriegsgeneration, 1955-1965/69 "geburtenstarke Jahrgänge". Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-Boomer#/media/Datei:Bev%C3%B6lkerungsentwicklung_Deutschland.svg

Answer (score 6):

Die Webseite https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/, ein privates Namensforschungsprojekt von [Knud Bielefeld](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knud_Bielefeld), bietet sogenannte "Hitlisten" für Deutschland ab 1890, sowohl für [einzelne Jahre](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/jahrgang) als auch für [Jahrzehnte](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/25320-jahrzehnte.htm). Wie die Ranglisten ermittelt wurden, beschreibt Bielefeld [auf seiner Webseite](https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/446-quelle.htm).

In den Ranglisten gibt es Namen, wie *Alexander*, die über Generationen gerne vergeben werden, aber auch Namen, wie *Horst*, die nur zu bestimmten Zeiten beliebt waren und später weniger gebräuchlich wurden.

Zu vielen Namen bietet die Seite eine Häufigkeitsstatistik an, an der man die Zeit, wann sie besonders beliebt waren, gut ablesen kann. Hier das Diagramm für *Horst:*

[image: Häufigkeitsstatistik für den Vornamen Horst]

Mithilfe der "Hitlisten" und der Häufigkeitsstatistiken, kannst du Namen finden, die typisch für bestimmte Generationen sind und die von vielen Sprechern mit Menschen eines bestimmten Alters verbunden werden.